# css div height expender

Tags: html, css, expander

i'm trying to put an textarea expander on a div and i can't find the right element to set , here explanation of what i'm trying to do :

in the textarea input tags in the bottom corner there is expander for the user to set the size he wants hes textarea to be

my question is , is there a way to put something like that on a div? i don't looking for javascript code , css or html would be great.

Comment: "is there a way to put something like that on a div?" NO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CSS3 `resize: both;`, as seen here: http://dhtmlexamples.com/2011/01/20/creating-a-user-resizable-div-tag-using-css3/

```
<style type="text/css">
    .isResizable {
        background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2);
        font-size: 2em;
        border: 1px solid black;
        overflow: hidden;
        resize: both;
        width: 160px;
        height: 120px;
        min-width: 120px;
        min-height: 90px;
        max-width: 400px;
        max-height: 300px;
    }
</style>

<div class="isResizable">The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</div>
```

Comment: it work great in ff but in chrome it mess up all the child divs and does not work on other browser , i prefer not using it right now but thank you.